# How to investigate why SqlConnection takes too long to open?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

In our testing environment, opening a SqlConnection takes around 5 seconds. I would like to investigate why it is taking so long, but I am not sure where to look at. Until the connection is open there are no entries in the SqlProfiler. 
The sql server (ver 2012) is running on a separate machine and we are connecting to it from another computer in the same network. We see the 5 second freeze in console applications as well as from the IIS (ASP.NET). The communication itself is fast.

Here's a screenshot from dotTrace:

[image: dotTrace]

What can I do to investigate what exactly is taking those 5 seconds? Thanks.

**Update**: 
Thanks everyone for great comments. It was the authentication - once we switched from integrated to sql authentication, the slowdowns were gone.

Comment: What type of connection is it? (Named pipes, IP...?) What authentication are you using? Have you tried it on other machines? Have you tried it on the same machine as the database?

Comment: is it also slow when SSMS connects from there? consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269268/initial-connection-to-sql-server-connection-is-slow-why

Comment: Drill down further into the stack trace. The screenshot stops short of the conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here go the usual best bets:

- Change the connection string from SSPI to SQL Authentication. If SQL authentication is faster > focus on authentication providers
- Change the connectivity from tcp/ip to named pipes. If named pipes are faster > focus on networking stack
- Change connection string from using host name to fully qualified host name. If faster > fix DNS/WINS properties. See also [Initial connection to SQL Server Connection Is Slow. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269268/initial-connection-to-sql-server-connection-is-slow-why).
- Change connection string from using host name to IP address. If faster, fix DNS lookup. See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807748eb-51c8-4702-b7e9-fa32b7028747/sqlconnectionopen-takes-up-to-5-seconds-first-time-its-called-why-is-it-so-slow-using-net-35?forum=sqldataaccess