# SQL Server initial connection very slow in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server

We have multiple .NET applications that used connecting to SQL Server 2016 through the IP address.

Now, we have set up a domain name connected to 2 IP addresses. The initial connection is very slow, anything between 25 and 40 seconds.

Here is the connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=lpc:chiangmaiserver.ch,51231;Database=ContactDatabase;User ID=****;Password=p@****;Connect Timeout=60;
```

The strange thing is that sometimes, the connection gets fast for a few minutes, then goes back to slow again.

The same domain used in SSMS does not have the issue.

If we revert to IP address the problem disappears.

I tried all the solutions proposed in previous posts, none of them is working.

Comment: Why are you using oledb ..you should use use sqlconnection class of dotnet..?

Comment: I tried both, it doesn't make any difference. We use oledb for legacy reasons.

Comment: I hope ..delay is not at sql end ..this is because of ip address resolution time...if domain are provided by some ISP..you should connect him

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269268/initial-connection-to-sql-server-connection-is-slow-why

Comment: Yes, I did already tried all this but it doesn't help. And the fact that SSMS doesn't have the problem points more to a connection string issue in .NET than a domain conversion issue.

Comment: Why are you using lpc (Shared Memory Protocol)? it only works if server is local. Also it's better to use native client `Provider=SQLNCLI11.1` than the legacy `SQLOLEDB`.

Comment: I tried with SQLNCLI11.1, it doesn't improve. I added lpc just for testing, but it doesn't make any difference either. The weird thing is that sometimes, it starts working normally for a few log ins, then goes back to long initial delay again.

Comment: I added a named pipe and the problem is gone. Thank you to both of you for your time.

Comment: I would recommend using a named pipe instead of lpc, for an explaination of why, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/175669/13631126